# How to test controller that using data from factory?Using Karma +Jasmine on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, controller, karma-jasmine

How to test this factory and controller using karma and jasmine,do I need angular.mocks.js? Is it possible to test witout mocks? And how to make my test look like to test things like this? 
Sorry I`m new in testing:(

Service:

```
app.factory('httpProvide', function ($http) {
function Provider() {
  Provider.prototype.getAll = function () {
    return $http.get('/all').then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
function main($scope, httpProvide) {
  var httpProvide = new httpProvide.Provider();
  var getAll = function () {
    httpProvide.getAll().then(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: As I know, Jasmine has built-in spies, and via spy you can set mock data for service method

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure your code would work, with or without the tests. Also in your controller, you have httpProvide.getALL() but where is getALL()? Did you perhaps mean httpProvide.loadAllAlbums()?

Comment: Sorry,I copied bad.Fixed.